# How to resolve "googleapi: Error 403: The caller does not have permission, forbidden"

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp, google-cloud-iam

I am using terraform to build infra in GCP. I am trying to assign roles to a `service account` using terraform but unable to do so. Below is my code:

sa.tf:

```
resource "google_service_account" "mojo-terra" {
  account_id   = "mojo-terra"
  description  = "Service account used for terraform script"
}

resource "google_project_iam_member" "mojo-roles" {
  count = length(var.rolesList)
  role =  var.rolesList[count.index]
  member = "serviceAccount:${google_service_account.mojo-terra.email}"
}
```

dev.tfvars:

```
rolesList = [
    "roles/iam.serviceAccountUser"
]
```

cloudbuild logs:

```
Step #2: Error: Error when reading or editing Resource "project \"poc-dev\"" with IAM Policy: Error retrieving IAM policy for project "poc-dev": googleapi: Error 403: The caller does not have permission, forbidden
Step #2: 
Step #2: 
Step #2: 
Step #2: Error: Error when reading or editing Resource "project \"poc-dev\"" with IAM Member: Role "roles/iam.serviceAccountUser" Member "serviceAccount:asadsfs@poc-dev-1221.iam.gserviceaccount.com": Error retrieving IAM policy for project "poc-dev": googleapi: Error 403: The caller does not have permission, forbidden
Step #2:
```

Below are the roles attached to my `cloudbuild service account`:
`Custom Role cloudbuild, Cloud Build Service Account, Service Account Admin, Create Service Accounts, Delete Service Accounts, Service Account User, Storage Admin`

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The service account providing authorization to Terraform is missing the permission `resourcemanager.projects.getIamPolicy` which is the source of the error message.

The service account is also missing the permission `resourcemanager.projects.setIamPolicy` which is required to change IAM policies.

Those permissions are part of the role `roles/resourcemanager.projectIamAdmin` (Project IAM Admin).

To list the roles assigned to the service account:

```
gcloud projects get-iam-policy <YOUR GCLOUD PROJECT ID> \
--flatten="bindings[].members" \
--format='table(bindings.role)' \
--filter="bindings.members:<YOUR SERVICE ACCOUNT>"
```

To list the permissions that a role contains:

```
gcloud iam roles describe roles/resourcemanager.projectIamAdmin
```

To add the required role to the service account:

```
gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding <YOUR GCLOUD PROJECT ID> \
--member=serviceAccount:<YOUR SERVICE ACCOUNT> \
--role=roles/resourcemanager.projectIamAdmin
```

Comment: Hi, I have assigned Project IAM admin role to the cloudbuild service account. Now, I am getting this error

`Step #2: 
Step #2: Error: Request "Create IAM Members roles/iam.serviceAccountUser serviceAccount:mojo-terra@poc-de.iam.gserviceaccount.com for \"project \\\"poc-de"\"" returned error: Error applying IAM policy for project "poc-de": Error setting IAM policy for project "poc-de": googleapi: Error 403: Policy update access denied., forbidden
Step #2: 
Step #2:   on serviceAccount.tf line 34, in resource "google_project_iam_member" "mojo-roles":
Step #2: `

Comment: @Pritish If you are getting that error, you did not grant the role correctly. Run my first command and post the output in your question.